# retain textarea values after submit

Tags: javascript, html

i have a situation where on pressing Enter key, the content of a text area should get submitted. But i want the contents to remain in the textarea. So that the previously entered text is visible.
i tried the below code, but it wont work

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function submitenter(myfield,e)
{
var keycode;
if (window.event) keycode = window.event.keyCode;
else if (e) keycode = e.which;
else return true;

if (keycode == 13)
{
myfield.submit();
return true;
}
function populatedText(){
var myvalue = document.getElementById("cmd");
document.getElementById("cmd").innerHTML = myvalue.value;
}
}
</script>

</head>
<body>
<FORM onKeyPress="submitenter(this,event)" class="cmdForm" method="post">
<textarea rows="15" cols="100" name="cmdEntered"        id="cmdEntered">$cmdEntered</textarea>


</FORM>
```

Comment: What is `$cmdEntered`? Where did you define it? Are you actually saving it somewhere using PHP?

Comment: when form is submitted, page is refreshed, so, you have two options: to use server side language, e.g. PHP sessions, or to submit form with ajax.

Answer (score 0):

```
if you are using php you can use the below code or if you are using some other server side language change it to the corresponding one. Basic idea is same just submit the form to the same page .



</head>
<body>
<?php 
$cmdEntered = $_POST['cmdEntered'];

?>

<FORM class="cmdForm" method="post" action="same_page_name">
<textarea rows="15" cols="100" name="cmdEntered"        id="cmdEntered">
echo $cmdEntered;
</textarea>


</FORM>
```

Comment: If you want text area to behave like a cmd prompt, then use onkeyup event with that textarea

Answer (score -1):

you can use cache in order store the input typed! so that you can display the same text in the textarea after submitting the form.

if you still want to stay on the same page even after submitting the text, it is better to use ajax to submit your data which triggers on clicking the enter button.

Answer (score -1):

Your code should be like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function submitenter(myfield,e)
{
var keycode;
if (window.event) keycode = window.event.keyCode;
else if (e) keycode = e.which;
else return true;

if (keycode == 13)
{
myfield.submit();
populatedText();
return true;
}

}

function populatedText(){
var textarea_value = document.getElementById("cmdEntered").value;
document.getElementById("cmdEntered").value = textarea_value;
}
</script>

</head>
<body>
<FORM onKeyPress="submitenter(this,event)" class="cmdForm" method="post">
<textarea rows="15" cols="100" name="cmdEntered"        id="cmdEntered">$cmdEntered</textarea>
</FORM>
```

Comment: Can you explain what this does? You are setting the value of the textarea to the value of that same textarea.. what is the use?

Comment: i want the textarea to behave like a command prompt, where the user can see the previously entered values.